# SQL-Alchemy reuse column definitions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to reuse the column definitions across all tables to avoid mix types between tables.

It's a common issue on DW to have the same column in many tables.
Using SqlAlchemy Core.

```
t_teachers = Table(
    'teachers', metadata,
    Column('teacher_uid', String(20), primary_key=True),
    Column('first_name', String(50)),
    Column('last_name', String(50)),
)

t_students = Table(
    'students', metadata,
    Column('student_uid', String(20), primary_key=True),
    Column('first_name', String(50)),
    Column('last_name', String(50)),
)

exams = Table(
    'exams', metadata,
    Column('exam_id', String(20), primary_key=True),
    Column('teacher_uid', String(20), ForeignKey('teachers.teacher_uid'), nullable=False),
    Column('student_uid', String(20), ForeignKey('students.student_uid'), nullable=False),
    Column('points', Integer),

)

exam_marts = Table(
    'exams_marts', metadata,
    Column('teacher_first_name', String(50)),
    Column('teacher_last_name', String(50)),
    Column('student_first_name', String(50)),
    Column('student_last_name', String(50)),
    Column('exam_name', String(50)),
    Column('points', Integer),
)
```

Comment: With proper database design, you'd probably have a `user` table and columns referring to `user.id` as a foreign key. I really don't know what you're asking in this instance.

Comment: You should'nt have 5 different tables with same column. You only should have one table, and other tables referencing this table. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Maybe the user_name wasn't a good example. There are some columns that are not referable, and some tables are acting as data marts.

Comment: It still wouldn't make much sense to me. You need a [mcve] to show the actual issue you're talking about

Comment: `exam_marts` (which is probably a typo in itself) is repeating data already in `t_teachers` and `t_students`. As suggested, you should be looking at normalization

Comment: The data on the marts are summarized and not normalized on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
def mixin_factory():
    return (sa.Column("created", sa.Date),)


tablename_table = sa.Table(
    "tablename",
    metadata,
    *mixin_factory()
)
```

Comment: +1 and read more on [Composing Mapped Hierarchies with Mixins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html#composing-mapped-hierarchies-with-mixins)